# Eigenvalues of symmetric part of $(A+B)^{-1} B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I want to analyze the equation $z^TMz$ where $M = (A+B)^{-1}B$, and where $A$ is symmetric positive definite, and $B$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, and compare $z^TMz$ to just $z^T z$.
I want to say something about how the number $z^TMz$ may scale when I add some positive semi-definite matrix $C$ to either $A$ or $B$  (this happens when I add data to my estimation problem, where all of this comes from).
Due to the specific form of the equation, it suffices to look at the symmetric part of $M$, namely $$G := \frac{1}{2}(M^T+ M) = \frac{1}{2} \left(B(A + B)^{-1} + (A + B)^{-1}B \right) $$
Thus, saying something about the eigenvalues of $G$ will help.

My questions are:

- Can we characterize (e.g. bound from above/below) the eigenvalues of $G$ somehow from $A, B$?
- What is the difference in this characterization when we add $C$ to $A$ or $B$?

---

Adding the matrix $C$ to $A$ results in
$$G_A = \frac{1}{2} \left(B(A + B + C)^{-1} + (A + B + C)^{-1}B \right) $$
while adding some (possibly different) $\bar C$ to $B$ gives
$$G_B = \frac{1}{2} \left((B+\bar C)(A + B + \bar C)^{-1} + (A + B + \bar C)^{-1}(B+ \bar C) \right) $$

From these equations it seems that an answer to the first question may assist the second one.
We know that $G, G_A, G_B$ will have real eigenvalues, and I expect that there can be both negative and positive eigenvalues in all problems, still the values seem to shrink as $C$ is added, but more so when it is added to $A$ rather than $B$.

Comment: A starting point for obtaining bounds for the eigenvalues of $M$ would be to use Theorem 3 from [this classic paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/77B/jresv77Bn1-2p61_A1b.pdf) and   the characterization of extremum eigenvalues of symmetric/Hermitian matrices (like $A+B$ and $B$) as extremum values of the respective Rayleigh quotient. Are you familiar with this characterization? A good source for this theory is the book "Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: Your first question is a bit confusing. You said you wanted to study $z^TMz$, but in your question you said you wanted bounds for the eigenvalues of $M$. Since $M$ is not symmetric, those are two different questions.

Comment: @user1551 as I state further below, it suffices to look at $G$, so I guess it can be changed to analyzing $G$.

Comment: @platypus The book by Horn and Johnson is my best friend:) This paper looks useful!

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of $M$ will be real, despite $M$ not being symmetric, you can work directly with $M$ and avoid considering its symmetric part $G$.  This follows from Theorem 3 in the paper mentioned above. Do you see how? It would also help to know if the perturbations to be added to $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary or also symmetric and/or positive (semi)-definite.

Comment: @platypus Yes, they are symmetric (since C is PSD). The paper helped *a lot*, I'm very greatful, I can post my answer below.

Comment: @platypus I am sure you are right, but what is the argument for that $M$ has only real eigenvalues?

Comment: @smallStackBigFlow This follows from what you wrote in the answer, an eigenvalue of $(A+B)^{-1}B$ is of the form $z_1/z_2$ with $z_1 \in F(B)$ and $z_2 \in F(A+B)$, where $F(A+B), F(B)$ are the fields of values of the matrices $A+B$ and $B$ defined in the answer.  And clearly $F(A+B), F(B) \subset \mathbb{R}$, because $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. From this, you can also conclude that the eigenvalues of $M$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the *field of values* I was able to characterize some useful properties of the equation $z^T M z$ with this particular definition.
The field of values is a set defined as $F(A) = \{ z^T A z | z^Tz = 1\}$ (here I do not need to work with complex stuff).
The following will just give approximations, but that is nice.
Regarding comparing $z^T M z$ to $z^T z$, this was rather simple (to approximate), since $eig(I - A) = 1 - eig(A)$.

Due to the [Rayleigh-Ritz theorem](https://planetmath.org/rayleighritztheorem), it suffices (for my application) to look at the eigenvalues of $G$.
For a symmetric matrix $A$, then $F(A) = [\min eig(A), \max eig(A)]$ (that's the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem).

From theorems in the paper cited by [@platypus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/40141/platypus) we have that
$$
eig((A+B)^{-1} B) \in \frac{F(B)}{F(A) + F(B)}
$$
where set arithmetic is defined elementwise.
This means that
$$
\max eig((A+B)^{-1} B) \leq \frac{\max eig(B)}{\min eig(A) + \min eig(B)}
$$
and
$$
\min eig((A+B)^{-1} B) \geq \frac{\min eig(B)}{\max eig(A) + \max eig(B)}
$$

Then it is quite simple to see what possibly happens if we add some positive semi-definite matrix $C$ to either $A$ or $B$. However, it depends on how the eigenspace of $C$ relates to the matrix it is added to.